# Text recognition in non-english language

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, machine-learning, neural-network

I have implemented a text detection algorithm in Hindi and it is working perfectly well, and have localised the textual region. Now I am looking for converting the textual regions to digital format which can be used by Google translate API. Any help regarding how I can convert it into digital format? (I have looked into SVM,ANN etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look into OCR.

The Tesseract OCR engine (open source) has language data available for many languages including Hindi, so that could be a good place to start. It can be integrated into OpenCV as well.

If you'd like to just use OpenCV then one of the Machine Learning methods (KNN, SVM) may be best, you'll need to train it yourself to recognise characters.

Few links:

https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/ (Tesseract)

https://opencv-code.com/tutorials/how-to-read-the-digits-from-a-scratchcard/ (OpenCV + Tesseract)

http://blog.damiles.com/2008/11/basic-ocr-in-opencv/ (OpenCV only - KNN)

https://opencv-code.com/tutorials/how-to-integrate-tesseract-ocr-and-opencv/ (Integrating Tesseract & OpenCV)

Comment: I am looking at implementing the KNN or SVM  based methods but if tesseract can work for this i will try that thank you. (Sorry i donot have enough rep to upvote this otherwise i wudve :) )

Comment: No problem, I think you can close the question by just accepting the answer. I've also added another link on integrating Tesseract into OpenCV that might be helpful.